# Route restrictions of a particular area/city in Here Maps API

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to get the route restrictions of a particular area/city using here api?
My objective is to visualise the route restrictions of a particular city.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to draw restrictions as an icons on the map, or do you want to calculate route which avoids certain areas?

Comment: @Tomas Yes, I want to draw restrictions on the map.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter to avoid areas

`avoidAreas` 
and to avoid countries  `excludeCountries=BOL,PRY,URY` which takes a list of ISO 3166-1-alpha-3 country codes.

Please find the [source](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) of documentation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is not what I was asking.  What I want is a way to extract the route restrictions of an area such as, an area a truck can't enter, a road which can't be crossed, a heavy traffic area etc and get the data in a kml file or something.

Comment: Is there a way by which I can get the restrictions from here maps and draw it on the map.

Comment: There is no direct API but you find something relevant here https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/layers-indexes-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

[Map Tile API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-base-trucknopttile.html) can return map tiles with truck restrictions (you need your own apikey in order to see that tile):

https://4.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/trucknopttile/newest/normal.day/10/301/384/512/png8?apikey={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this data in image format is of no use to me. Want this in a form which can be parsed. Something like a kml file or something. Does here maps provide that?

Comment: Normally to get label's and POI's geometries you could simply add ```&metadata=metaonly&mgen=2```, unfortunately it doesn't return any truck restriction information.